# ResNet testing accuracy calculation

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I have taken the stock ResNet and trained it only to identify a small set of custom objects. My training set is comprised of images of these custom objects and their associated bounding box tags. I then train the ResNet model via TensorFlow and try to test it on a few other images, which do not have associated tags/bounding boxes. When I do the testing, the model identifies the objects with a bounding box, which is great, but those boxes each come with an accuracy percentage, i.e. 92%. How is ResNet calculating this accuracy percentage?? I can't seem to find the actual calculation it is doing.

Thanks

Comment: Edit: The scores are coming from 'detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0') .. any idea where to find this detection_scores source code or what it is actually doing?

Comment: Where is the code? But, if you are not getting your results compared with corresponding ground truths, then, there is no point in wondering about this accuracy. Does the test results are correct in consideration with the class label and is the bounding box coming alright for the class? If that is happening, then, you need not wonder about this atleast.